# c# Linq foreach

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help?

I tried to create a Linq but don't find the right syntax:

This is the code I want to update to Linq:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
foreach (Person p in persons)
{
   foreach (Course c in p.courses)
   {
      if (c.id == q.id)
      {
         list.Add(p);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `q.id` in the inner if statement?

Comment: Do you really want to add the same "Person" to the list multiple times?

Comment: Look for questions on "nested foreach" + "LINQ" if you want to see more examples.

Comment: List<Person> list = persons.Where(x => x.Courses.Any(c => c.id == q.id)).ToList();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `SelectMany` that will allow you to flatten the inner collection.

```
var list = persons
    .SelectMany(p => p.cources.Where(c => c.id == q.id).Select(_ => p))
    .ToList();
```

This will filter the inner courses by the id and repeat the same person for each match and then flatten all those into a list.  However it seems like you'd only want to add a person to the list once in which case you'd actually want

```
var list = persons
    .Where(p => p.cources.Any(c => c.id == q.id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yeah, I've fixed that and included what is likely the actual query they want instead of the one that does exactly what they are currently doing.